# Highscore resets when app is closed or view changes. How do I permanently retain the highscore in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsuserdefaults

Instance variables:

```
var Score: Int64 = 0

 var highscore: Int64 = 0
      func saveHighScore(high:Int) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(high, forKey:        "highscore")

    }
  func highScore() -> Int {
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
   } func resetHighScore() {NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("highscore")
    }

///METHOD. ALL OF THIS IS WORKING FINE. HIGH SCORE SHOWS AND UPDATES WHILE IN THE GAME.

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
 @IBAction func Ans1(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(CorrectAnswer) == "1" {

        // Calculate the number of points
        Score += 10
        scoreLabel.text = "Score:\(Score)"
        if (Score > highscore) {
            highscore = Score
            highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "High Score : %i",    highscore) as String
        }
```

Do I need to add anything here? For data to save and reload on relaunch of the application?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to removeObjectForKey in NSUserDefaults whenever the view disappears or the app enters the background?

Comment: When does the method `resetHighScore()` gets called?

Comment: also may I observe that `forKey: "highscore"` is rather curious sort of a key. Some symbols you have added or just appeared while copy pasting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about removing ObjectForKey?

Comment: Those weird symbols appeared when I posted the question. They are not actually in my code. The resetHighScore doesn't get called anywhere else.

Comment: @Swifty123 he means when do you call the method where you remove the object which holds your highScore? That maybe the reason you can't access it when you return to active state

Comment: Okay are you using `AppDelegate`'s App State methods to perform actions as per your App's state? Like `applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` , `(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` etc?

Comment: Oh! Ok. Could you possible give me an idea of how to do that? I am quite new to Swift. I love it, but on occasion it challenges me...like now! Thanks

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; This is in my did enter background delegate.

Comment: First of all please be sure that method `resetHighScore()` is not being called anywhere where it shouldn't. When that's done, use those delegate methods to set your highscore again while entering the foreground again. It will be more helpful if you could show implementation of `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I don't have anything in viewWillDisappear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Saving highscore using NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269686/swift-saving-highscore-using-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the code, the variable 'highscore' is reset to 0. you should use an 'if' statement to see if there is an integer in nsuserdefaults with a key of 'highscore', if not, set the value for the key 'highscore' to be 0, else, set the variable highscore to be equal to the value for the key 'highscore'. I apologise in advance for the lack of code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you never call your methods `saveHighScore()` or `highscore()`. Instead, every time you load the view, the highscore variable is set to 0.

In your lifecycle methods like `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()`, you have to call and set it, like this: `highscore = highscore()`. That should get the user defaults and set the highscore variable in your view to what is saved.

In your `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` or better yet `viewWillDisappear()`, you should call `saveHighScore(highscore)`.

That way, all your progress should always be saved and persist through closing and reopening the app.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is what you're looking for:

```
let highscore = 1000
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setValue(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Ref: [Swift - Saving highscore using NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269686/swift-saving-highscore-using-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Could you advise me where in my code that should go? Does it go in the viewDidLoad?