# NSUser Defaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, sigabrt

I have tried an answer which doesn't work: [Swift Saving user NSUser Defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269686/swift-saving-highscore-using-nsuserdefaults).

My problem is that i want to save : `var myDict = [Int:String]()` permanently using NSUser defaults.

My code is :

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

@IBAction func AddOneWord(sender: AnyObject) {
    if newWord.text != "" {

        myDict.updateValue(newWord.text!, forKey: 1)

        self.Word1Dictionnary.text = myDict[1]

        userDefaults.setValue(myDict, forKey: "1")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have this error when clicking on the button on my app (which is running) : [Thread 1 : Signal SIGABRT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZIHx.png).

Comment: Could you please show what the error says? Thanks!

Comment: It is in my post the link "Thead 1 : Signal SIGABRT" and it doesn't say anything else.

Comment: You should get something in the debug log at the bottom. What does it say?

Comment: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Comment: You have 2 options: Declare the dictionary as `[String:String]` or use a custom class conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol. And don't use `setValue:forKey` and `synchronize()`. The former syntax is `setObject:forKey`, the latter is not needed.

Comment: Ok I have understand what you said. Can I use some keys like : word1, word2, word3... I will code them like " word \n " where n will be 1,2,3...n ?

Comment: You can use everything as long as it's a string. But why don't you use the string representation `"1"` rather than the integer value `1`?

Comment: Ok, so is that ok? => userDefaults.setValue(myDict, forKey: "1")

Comment: How can I retrieve the value from a NSUserDefaults?
I have tried that : self .NSUserSee.text = userDefaults.valueForKey("1")
(Where NSUser is a UILabel)

Comment: Don't use `setValue:forKey: / valueForKey:` unless you know and need the special behavior. String values are retrieved with `stringForKey:` and written with `setObject:forKey:`

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` can only store property-list objects. As noted in the [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2):

> And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects.

You cannot store an `[Int: String]` in `NSUserDefaults`. The key must be a string.

Comment: Yes, I have understand that point now, but I'm not able to do it. To store my [Int: String] I tried to use : 
        userDefaults.setValue(myDict, forKey: "Dictionnary")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
I have the same error : (red signal) Signal SIGABRT. I have already looked some videos and posts to solve it but it doesn't work.

Comment: My point is you can't store an [Int: String] in NSUserDefaults. The key cannot be an Int. The key has to be a string to store it in defaults. User Defaults is not general-purpose storage. It's meant for storing preferences.

Comment: Ok I have understand what you said. Can I use some keys like : word1, word2, word3... I will code them like " word \n " where n will be 1,2,3...n ?

Comment: See vadian's comment above. You can use anything you like, as long as the key is a string.